# Questions about a college project

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

I have 
the struct:

```
typedef struct Rental {
  int nDays;
  float kmsDriven;
  char carLicensePlate[LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH+1];
  char *clientName;
  char chargingCategory;
} Rental;
```

Different -Rental type- structs are stored and accessed via a dynamically allocated array of pointers (here is a part of the project):

```
int main (){

    Rental *rentals;

    int max_num;

    printf("Give a number of rentals you would like to store and manage: ");

    scanf("%d", &max_num);

    rentals=(Rentals *)malloc(max_num * (sizeof(Rental)))
```

This is what I have thought of so far but I can't understand it completely...so:

1. I'm having trouble understanding how `*rentals` can be an array. I mean shouldn't I declare it at least this way: `Rental *rentals[];`?  I know that if I compile the above code I will see an error...but why?
2. I've read numerous posts here in Stack Overflow about doing this with double pointers (`Rental **rentals;`) but the code other people have posted is often very hard for me to read (I don't know all the functions etc. etc.)
3. Let's say I have the object `rentals[0]` which will be a pointer towards `rentals`. If I wanted to pass the struct to a function, should I write:
   `variable=function(*arguments*... , Rental *rentals[0]);`?

Comment: not knowing the C library functions is a very good time to read/understand the man page for each function being used.  On my ubuntu linux 14.04, when working with code, I always have a terminal open so I can enter `man <functionName>` As I have found my 'editing' memory is not perfect, especially on remembering all the details.

Answer (score 1):

1. `rentals` is a pointer, not an array, but it is a pointer to the first (zeroth) element of a block of `max_num` structures, so it can be treated as an array in that you can use `rentals[n]` to refer to the n<sup>th</sup> element of the array.
2. *This is not a question and hence it is unanswerable.*

> 3. Let's say I have the object `rentals[0]` which will be a pointer towards `rentals`. If I wanted to pass the struct to a function, should I write: `variable=function(*arguments*... , Rental *rentals[0]);`?

- `rentals[0]` is not a pointer; it is a `struct Rental` or `Rental`.
- If you want to pass the structure to the function, you write:

  ```
  variable = function(…args…, rentals[0]);
  ```

  If you want to pass a pointer to the structure to the function, you write:

  ```
  variable = function(…args…, &rentals[0]);
  ```

  or:

  ```
  variable = function(…args…, rentals);
  ```

  These pass the same address to the function.

You should be error checking the call to `scanf()` to make sure you got a number, and you should error check the number you got (it should be strictly positive, not zero or negative), and you should error check the value returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: thank you for your reply...i will put in test what you have told me and i will hit you with some other Qs later :D

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array (for example `char buffer[10];` the variable is actually pointing to that array. Pointers and arrays are very close together. In fact when you have a pointer where you store an array of data (just like your case with `malloc`) you can do something like `pointer[0]` and `pointer[1]` to get the correct element.

With a pointer in order to access an element you'd normally use `*(pointer +1)` to get the element on position 1, this is exactly the same as `pointer[1]`.

When you want to pass a `struct` in an array, you can either give it by value like this:

```
void function(struct mystruct var)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct var;
    function(var);
}
```

Or by reference (passing the address instead of the data - this is ideal if your structs are big in size) :

```
void function(struct mystruct *var)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct var;
    function(&var);
}
```

By using an array, you can do it like this (still by reference):

```
void function(struct mystruct *var)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct var[10];
    function(&var[0]);
}
```

And using a pointer (to an array) :

```
void function(struct mystruct *var)
{
    //...
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct *var;
    var = malloc( sizeof(struct mystruct) *10 );

    //This will pass the address of the whole array (from position 0)
    function(&var);

    //This will pass the address of the selected element
    function(&var[0]);
}
```

As you can see, declaring an array or a pointer is almost the same, expect that you have to initialize the pointer-array yourself (with `malloc`) and as with anything created with `malloc` you have to `free` it yourself too.

Comment: Someone edited my answer on the last lines about pointer to an array, from `var = malloc( sizeof(var) *10 );` to `var = malloc( 10 * sizeof(*var) );`. I think that's wrong, because I want a pointer that points to an array of `struct mystruct`s not pointers to `struct mystruct`s. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe the editor was correct. Your `var` is a pointer to `struct mystruct`, and `*var` is the actual `struct mystruct`. Either way, you could rid all confusion by using `sizeof(struct mystruct)` instead.

Comment: Your initial statement is misleading: an array is *not* a pointer, although in many case the name of an array "decays" to a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: @AlexPogue oooh thanks I saw my mistake, `sizeof (struct mystruct )` is actually what I meant to type. I edited my answer.

Comment: @mlp Thanks for your comment! I saw my mistake and edited my answer.

Comment: You edited it, but you kept the fundamental wrongness "When you declare an array [...] you are actually creating a pointer to that array."

When you define an array, you actually create an array. Your claim that a pointer is created is wrong, R. O. N. G., wrong.

And if you use the word "declare" when you should use "define", I can't help you further.